# SSDT - auto increment DACPAC version only when project changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have a dacpac auto deploy code that compares the current dacpac version in the database and the dacpac application file that I distribute along with my app.

If database is in a lower version then I run it (Using DacFX).

Unfortunate it takes a considerable time to execute, so I would like to run this task only when my dacpac schema was really changed.

Without dark magic, is there any way to detect that my database project was changed (any file) and auto-increment the dacpac version?